# What is the difference between SQLiteOpenHelper.close() and SQLiteDatabase.close()?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

What happens when I call `SQLiteOpenHelper.close()` and what happens when I call `SQLiteDatabase.close()`?

For my android applications, I always create subclass of `Application` class which have single instance of `MySQLiteOpenHelper` which is subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` that will be shared by all application components like Services, Activities and BroadcastReceivers.

In `MySQLiteOpenHelper`, I have single instance of `SQLiteDatabase`. I create the instance of `MySQLiteOpenHelper` in Application.onCreate() method and never call `close()` on any of `SQLiteOpenHelper` or `SQLiteDatabase` instances. Though I call close() explicitly on every cursor object returned by the `query()` and on every `SQLiteStatement` I use to insert, update or delete the data.

Untill now, it was working fine without any problem. But recently I am getting crashlogs from user's. The exception thrown is `SQLiteDatabaseLockedException`. I read documentation which says

> Thrown if the database engine was unable to acquire the database locks it needs to do its job.

I don't understand how can their be problem in acquiring the database lock when there is only single database instance I am using and documentation says that all database calls are serialized by the system. Also I am not starting or ending any database transaction using beginTransaction() or any other related method.

After some search I think that I should call `close()` on my database connection.

My questions are:

1. Am I using the correct approach here(I don't need to share data across other apps or 3rd party app so not using ContentProviders)?
2. When should I close the database connection?
3. Also, should I call close on `MySQLiteOpenHelper` or `SQLiteDatabase`?

> Code for MySQLiteOpenHelper.java:

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static String TAG = Common.MAIN_TAG + "MySQLiteOpenHelper";

        public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 19;

        private static String DB_PATH = null;
        public static final String DB_NAME = "data.sqlite";
        private SQLiteDatabase db;

        private final Context context;

        /**
         * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
         * access to the application assets and resources.
         * 
         * @param context
         */
        public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName().replace("/", "")
                    + "/databases/";
            this.context = context;
        }

        /**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
         * database.
         * */
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Log.v(TAG, "Create database checkpoint - 1");
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            // Log.v(TAG, "Create database checkpoint - 2");
            if (dbExist) {
                // Log.v(TAG,
                // "Create database checkpoint - 3 - database already exists");
            } else {
                // Log.v(TAG,
                // "Create database checkpoint - 3 - database needs to be copied");
                // Log.v(TAG, "Create database checkpoint - 4");
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                    checkDataBase();
                    // Log.v(TAG,
                    // "Create database checkpoint - 5 - database cpoied");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }

        void copyDatabaseToSdCard() throws IOException {
            if (Log.isInDebugMode()) {
                InputStream input = null;
                FileOutputStream output = null;

                int c;
                byte[] tmp;
                try {
                    File databaseFile = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            Common.MAIN_TAG + "sqlite");
                    if (databaseFile.exists()) {
                        databaseFile.delete();
                    }
                    databaseFile.createNewFile();
                    output = new FileOutputStream(databaseFile);
                    int i = 0;

                    input = new FileInputStream(new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME));
                    tmp = new byte[1024];
                    while ((c = input.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                        i++;
                        output.write(tmp, 0, c);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (input != null) {
                        input.close();
                    }
                    if (output != null) {
                        output.close();
                        output.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
         * time you open the application.
         * 
         * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
         */
        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            // Log.v(TAG, "Check database checkpoint - 1");
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                // checkDB = getWritableDatabase();
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                // Log.v(TAG,
                // "Check database checkpoint - 2 - got database file on device");
                checkDB.close();
                getWritableDatabase().close();
                // Log.v(TAG, "Check database checkpoint - 3");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.v(TAG,
                // "Check database checkpoint - 4 - database does not exists on device");
                // database does't exist yet.
                if (checkDB != null)
                    checkDB.close();
                // Log.v(TAG, "Check database checkpoint - 5");
            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        /**
         * Copies your database FROM your local raw-folder to the just created empty
         * database in the system folder, FROM where it can be accessed and handled.
         * This is done by transfering bytestream.
         * */
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            // Log.v(TAG, "Copy database checkpoint - 1");
            InputStream input = null;
            FileOutputStream output = null;
            SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;

            myDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, 0, null);
            if (myDB != null) {
                myDB.close();
            }

            int c;
            byte[] tmp;
            try {
                File databaseFile = new File(DB_PATH, DB_NAME);
                databaseFile.mkdirs();
                databaseFile.createNewFile();
                output = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
                int i = 0;

                input = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hcgtabletdb);
                tmp = new byte[1024];
                while ((c = input.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                    i++;
                    output.write(tmp, 0, c);
                }
                // Log.v(TAG, "Finished copying database");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Log.e(TAG, "Error in copying database" + DB_NAME);
            } finally {
                if (input != null) {
                    input.close();
                }
                if (output != null) {
                    output.close();
                    output.close();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            createDataBase();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }

        public int getIdFor(String name) {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM bloodpressure WHERE userid=" + userId
                + " ORDER BY createdon, timecreatedon";
            Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {});
            int id = cur.getInt(0);
            cur.close();
            return cur;
        }
}
```

> Code for MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication singleton;
    private MySQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
        // Some code
    }

    public MySQLiteOpenHelper getDatabaseHelper() {
        return dbHelper;
    }

}
```

> Using code in any of application components:

```
int id = MyApplication.getInstance().getDatabaseHelper().getIdFor("ashish");
```

Comment: Can you show how you create and access MySQLiteOpenHelper instance?

Comment: @boulder Please refer the edited question for code.

Comment: You SQLiteOpenHelper is seems to be used not as intended. SQLiteOpenHelper is a convenience class to create/hold/close/manage SQLiteDatabase instance in convenient way and you simply duplicate it's functionality. Intended use is just override abstract methods like onCreate(). After that you can easily and thread safe access database through getWritableDatabase() method.

Comment: And crash may be caused by you creating multiple instances of SQLiteDatabase inside you SQLiteOpenHelper override. Can't point exact place though.

Comment: @boulder I have edited the code above. Since I have preloaded database which I need to ship with the app, I have modified the functionality a little bit. Is that correct(please see edited code)? If not, can you please post tell me how should this be handled and answer 3 question that I have asked in my question?

Comment: Why just don't copy shipped database file to supposed location just before initializing MySQLiteOpenHelper instance? If it isn't already exist ofcourse.

Comment: Difference between SQLiteOpenHelper and SQLiteDatabase close() is that SQLiteOpenHelper just closes inner instance of SQLiteDatabase. And it does it in thread safe way.

Comment: Why just don't copy shipped database file to supposed location just before initializing MySQLiteOpenHelper instance?
---- Ok. I tried this just now, and it works for me. But what is the benefit? I am doing the same in my code as well. What's the differece?

Comment: For which close() to call, you are saying that I should use SQLiteDatabase.close() instead of SQLiteDatabase.close(). Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16038/discussion-between-boulder-and-ashish-pathak)

Answer (score 2):

there is no difference between `SQLiteOpenHeloper::close()` and `SQLiteDatabase::close()`.

`SQLiteOpenHeloper::close()` is just a wrapper around `SQLiteDatabase::close()`.

but as a rule of thumb, either let `SQLiteOpenHelper` manages your connections, or don't use it and manage it yourself.

see this blog post. I use `SQLiteOpenHelper` with my own pre-loaded database, but play nicely with `SQLiteOpenHelper`, letting it manage the connection.

[using a pre-loaded sqlite database with SQLiteOpenHelper](http://blog.kdehairy.com/2012/08/19/using-a-preloaded-sqlite-database-with-sqliteopenhelper/)

**Update**
This is the source code for `SQLiteOpenHelper::close()`:

```
/**
 * Close any open database object.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mIsInitializing) throw new IllegalStateException("Closed during initialization");

    if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        mDatabase.close();
        mDatabase = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `there is no difference between SQLiteOpenHeloper::close() and SQLiteDatabase::close()`. Do you have any references for this, any link to relevant documentation?